# Setting a Quartz.NET trigger to fire on a specific object instance

Tags: c#, quartz.net

How can I get Quartz to fire a trigger on an already created & initialized object?

e.g.

```
public class Foo : IJob
{
    public Foo ( configuration items ... ) { }
}

// Calling Code...
Foo f = new Foo( /*Non empty constructor*/ );
Schedular sched = new SchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
JobDetail jD = new JobDetail("fooDetail", null typeof(Foo));
Trigger trig = TriggerUtils.MakeSecondlyTrigger(15);
sched.ScheduleJob( jD, trig );
sched.Start();
```

As foo doesn't have a 0 args constructor Quartz.NET is having issues instantiating the Job and running it. Is there any way I can get Quartz to trigger the instance of Foo, f?

Please forgive me if I'm missing a fundamental fact about Quartz and its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Quartz.NET documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html) states: ( In very small writing!)

> Each (and every) time the scheduler executes the job, it creates a new instance of the class before calling its Execute(..) method. One of the ramifications of this behavior is the fact that jobs must have a no-arguement constructor.

So having Jobs with complex constructors is a no-no!

Time for Plan B:

I created one 'Master' Job. This job looked in the context.JobDetail.JobDataMap to determine which type of task *really* should be executed. The Execute function looked a little like:

```
public void Execute( JobExecutionContext context )
{
    JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

    // Execute the stored Task
    Foo taskToExecute = dataMap["Task"] as Foo;
    if ( taskToExecute != null )
    {
        taskToExecute.Execute();
    }           
}
```

This allows the Task to be created prior to the scheduling and the task instance to be run whenever the Master Task Fires e.g.

```
JobDetail detail = new JobDetail( "foo", null, typeof( MasterTask) );
detail.JobDataMap["Task"] = task;
```

I'm sure this violates some master Quartz rule, but it at least means I can do what needs to be done!

Answer (score 3):

You could implement your own [Quartz.Spi.IJobFactory](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/) (that uses an DI container) to define how jobs are created and initialized. Quartz does not allow to schedule already initialized job.

Here´s a JobFactory that uses [unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) to create jobs. In the container you could register the job type and define how the container should construct the job and how to resolve dependencies of the job.

```
public class UnityJobFactory : IJobFactory {

    public UnityJobFactory(IUnityContainer container) {
        Container = container;
    }

    public IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) {
        try {
            return Container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType, null) as IJob;
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new SchedulerException("Error on creation of new job", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I wired this up, the "normal quartz.net" items started failing.  ("Quartz.Job.FileScanJob, Quartz" for example)...  How did you handle this?  Did you register the concretes as themselves?  (I'm using Unity.config FYI).

Answer (score 0):

Don't put anything in the class implementing IJob, create a class that implement a IJobListener and make it listen to the job of your group.

```
var myJobListener = new YourClassImplementingIJobListener(param1, param2);
sched.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(myJobListener,GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("myJobGroup"));
```

More info on this here
http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html