# Schedule one-off job that works on a specific object instance

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Assume the following scenario:
I have a view model that should automatically close itself after a specific delay.

Something like this:

```
public AutoCloseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public void Close()
    {
        /* perform actions necessary to close
           the view model and its associated view */
    }

    protected override OnActivate()
    {
        // schedule job that calls Close on this instance, something like
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()...;
        trigger.Job = new DelegateJob(() => Close()); // <----
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);
    }
}
```

The line `trigger.Job = new DelegateJob(() => Close());` obviously doesn't work, because of the following reasons:

1. There exists no `Job` property on `ITrigger`.
2. A job class is supposed to be serializable.

**Question:**
Is there a way to do what I am trying to do with Quartz.net or am I trying to use it for something it wasn't designed for?

BTW: I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114698/setting-a-quartz-net-trigger-to-fire-on-a-specific-object-instance) but to me it looks like the accepted answer abuses Quartz.net and the other answer wouldn't help me.

Comment: How about a simple Timer?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Sure, that would work. It just has the problem that it makes my view model async, making it hard to unit test. Because I have other recurring tasks in my application I thought about introducing a scheduler and using it for all these "execute later" requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, i agree that a timer should be the preferred way to go. I feel a scheduler for this purpose is to complicate things.

Using a scheduler or a timer will both make async stuff.

If you do want to use a scheduler, you can communicate to your viewmodel using a [Messenger] to send a message that the given job is done, and register for that in the viewmodel.[1](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx)